# MySQL JSON_OVERLAPS ... how do I compare json from one table to a group of ID values from another table?

Tags: mysql, sql, json

I have 2 MySQL tables that look like this:

first_table: the "json_field" values are just lists of integers, but the field type is "json":

```
id   json_field
1    [1,2,3]
2    [2,3]
3    [1,3]
```

second_table: just a simple table with 2 fields (integer, varchar):

```
id   name
1    bob
2    sam
3    mary
```

I need a single query that gives me all rows from first_table for which json_field values intersect with any "id" value from second_table that satisfies a simple query condition of "where name = 'sam'" (e.g. using a subquery)

Here's what I have so far:

```
select * from first_table where 
    JSON_OVERLAPS(json_field, (select group_concat(id) from second_table where name = 'sam'))
```

This query gives this error, however:

"Invalid JSON text in argument 1 to function json_overlaps: "The document root must not be followed by other values." at position 1."

I also tried this thinking that I had to convert the result of group_concat to json first, but got an SQL syntax error:

```
select * from first_table where 
    JSON_OVERLAPS(json_field, JSON_OBJECT(select group_concat(id) from second_table where name = 'sam'))
```

The correct result should give me the following 2 rows, since those rows contain id = 2, which is the id that corresponds to "sam" in second_table

```
1   1,2,3
2   2,3
```

Please assume that I must use a json field type for "first_table". The schema that I outlined above cannot be changed.

Comment: I don't think your `json_field` column is defined with the JSON data type. A bare list of comma-separated values isn't valid JSON. A JSON array would require square brackets.

Comment: @BillKarwin you're correct... I updated the question to reflect this fix

Comment: Your GROUP_CONCAT() is also just producing a comma-separated list of values, not a valid JSON document. Perhaps you need [JSON_ARRAYAGG()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_json-arrayagg)?

Comment: I tried this, but it actually gives me a syntax error:

select * from first_table where JSON_OVERLAPS(json_field, JSON_ARRAYAGG(select group_concat(id) from second_table where name = 'sam'))

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select group_concat(id) from second_table where name = 'sam'))'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use GROUP_CONCAT(), because it returns a string, not a set of rows. It can't be used to compare to a JSON document, and it can't be used to convert into a JSON array.

Instead, use JSON_ARRAYAGG() on a *set of rows*. This function transforms the set of rows into a JSON array.

```
select id, json_pretty(json_field) from first_table
where json_overlaps(json_field, 
  (select json_arrayagg(id) from second_table where name='Sam')
);
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7a8d4f8a47042c1f9fa763c0689287ea

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT t1.id, CAST(t1.json_field AS CHAR), t2.id, t2.name
FROM t1
JOIN t2 ON JSON_OVERLAPS(t1.json_field, CAST(t2.id AS JSON))
WHERE t2.name = 'sam'
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6d065e49643b04d4630f0031096aa4ee

Comment: Thanks for sharing this! I think that this solution and the one provided by Bill Karwin both look good. I accepted his answer since the sql syntax is closer to what I currently have, so modifications to my code are minimal. I appreciate the insight and link.

Comment: @DarrenGates Both my and Bill's solutions are bad from the performance looking point (you may modify the queries and try to apply multivalued index). But my query is better - it allows the server to select optimal tables scanning order rather than Bill's solution. And in most cases scanning `second_table` then `first_table` will show higher performance, i.e. my solution will produce more productive plan.